# Get difference between old and new time

Tags: android

I need to know the difference value between old and new system time (after user changed it)

With following code I catch moment when user changed time:

```
<receiver android:name=".TimeChangeReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TIME_SET"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver> 

public class TimeChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = TimeChangeReceiver.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "changed time: " + new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    }
}
```

For example current time 10:00, user changed it to 11:00 - onReceive method called, but time already changed, how to get previous value - 10:00?

Comment: You need to store the old time somewhere.  You need to maintain this value somewhere in your own code.

Comment: Maybe store the old time as a `long` in `SharedPreferences`?

Comment: But in this case I would have to update this value every second....

Comment: Do You want to know if user changed time in Your app anywhere or in the complete System?

Comment: System. For example current time 10:00, user changed it to 11:00. In onReceive method called, but time already changed, how to get previous value - 10:00?;

Comment: You have to keep track of it. Find a suggestion below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Below you find a solution to calculate the previous value. I tried it out and you can find my implementation here
https://github.com/chrisport/setTimeIntent

The main idea is this:
You need a independent time to compare to, we can take
**SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()** which is the time since the device booted. 
Now we can calculate the difference between this elapsedTime and System.currentTimeMillis().
This difference will always be constant, unless the SystemTime has changed (e.g. by the user). In this case, we can calculate the new difference and compare them to determine **how much the it has changed**.

Let's do it:

1. Calculate the current difference:

   ```
   public static long getCurrentDifference() {
     long elapsedTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
     long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     return currentTime - elapsedTime;
   }
   ```
2. Store this difference at begining* to SharedPreferences
3. When SET_TIME is received, calculate the difference between the current difference and the stored difference

   ```
   long lastDifference = mySharedPrefs.getLastTimeDifference();

   //Calculate the new difference
   long currentDifference = getCurrentDifference();

   //Calculate the difference of the differences
   //this is the change the user made
   long userChangeInMillis = lastDifference - currentDifference;

   //and here we get the old time:
   long previousTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + userChangeInMillis;
   ```

You can also make a Date out of it (new Date(previousTime)).

*To always have an initial time difference, you can store it to SharedPreferences when the app is opened, when the device is booted (needs another BroadCastReceiver), as well as save the newly calculated difference after SET_TIME has been received.

Edit:

The output of my example looks like this:

```
Before it was Wed May 21 17:43:28 GMT+00:00 2014
Now it is:    Wed May 21 18:43:00 GMT+00:00 2014
```

Somehow SET_TIME is received twice. Therefore there are two Log-messages and the second one shows twice the current time, because I overwrite the lastDifference with the newly calculated one.

Comment: Sounds good! Accurate, no cumbersome background task... I like it.

Comment: But, if user restarts the device, this solution will not work.

Comment: @user123456 as written above, you need to register a BroadCastReceiver for startup (BOOT_COMPLETED), so you get notified when the phone has restarted.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge the only way is to have it saved before the receiver is called. At application startup for example:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ...
    @Override 
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        mReferenceTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
 ...
 }
```

Depending on the accuracy you need, you may have to update this reference time more often, using a background task for example (mind the battery!):

```
// at application startup:
mClkRef = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (hasToRun()) {
            mReferenceTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            sleep(A_REASONABLE_WHILE);
        }
    }

    ...
};

mClkRef.start();
```

In this case you would have to either control or dispose of/recreate this thread from `TimeChangeReceiver.onReceive()`.

Depending on what you have to do/how you app works, [`Handler.postDelayed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29) can also be an  interesting solution.

Comment: Should testing shows it works, Chrispo's solution is way better than mine.

Answer (score 0):

Chrisport,

I fixed the "Somehow SET_TIME is received twice. Therefore there are two Log-messages and the second one shows twice the current time, because I overwrite the lastDifference with the newly calculated one" that you were talking about.

Basically if the `mySharedPrefs.getLastTimeDifference()` is equal to -1, then don't log the difference.

I was getting the first log having the date of 1969, so I added an if statement and then it was fixed.